# Don't invoke edit mode on 'swipe to delete'

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have implemented an edit button in my Swift app with `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()`. Now when I swipe a cell on my table view to delete, the edit mode is invoked. Is there a way to make it so that the swipe to delete does not invoke edit mode? Do I have to make my own edit mode?